# Wordpress Array Conundrum

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, arraylist

I have the following array output which I'd like to merge:

```
004249512651280042495126512800424951265128
```

There are 3 seperate arrays there, which are outputting data from a database, which has these numbers populated. These are the arrays:

```
00424951265128
00424951265128
00424951265128
```

I've tried the array_merge function to merge the data but it doesn't seem to work, I still get the same output.

The array data comprises of the following numbers:

```
0
0
4249
5126
5128
```

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
$player_ids = get_post_meta($post_id,"sp_player", false);
$new_player_ids = array_merge($player_ids);
foreach ( $new_player_ids as $new_player_id ){
print_r ($new_player_id);
```

Is there another function I've not found yet? Am I doing something wrong here. I'm not sure why one array is being repeated more than once.

Comment: A few things: 1, what are you trying to do? What's the desired **result** you want? 2, your code is incomplete, missing a closing curly brace. 3, Happy New Year to you also!  (When you `print_r($new_player_id)`, what do you want it to output?)

Comment: Hi cale_b

It's all fixed now. Just waiting to close the question - think I have to wait 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Actually guys - figured it out. I had the code within a loop hence it was multiplying the array 3 times.

Fixed it woohoo!!

Thanks for looking